# Access attributes of html tag via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to access each Value of that array.

for example how can i get the "very_satisfied" value Via Jquery.

```
<div id="analysis" data-valuations='[{"very_satisfied":7,"satisfied":5,"neutral":1,"sad":1,"angry":1}]'></div>
```

I wish to get answer.

Comment: `$('#analysis').data('valuations').split('},{')[0].split(':')[1]`

Comment: `eval($('#analysis').data('valuations'))[0].very_satisfied`

Comment: `$('#analysis').data('valuations').slice(2,-2).split('},{').map(v=>v.split(':')).filter(v=>v[0]=='very_satisfied')[0][1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to have a valid JSON in the attribute. Like this:

```
<div id="analysis" data-valuations='[{"very_satisfied":7},{"satisfied":5},{"neutral":1},{"sad":1},{"angry":1}]'></div>
```

(just need doublequotes for properties and singlequotes for attribute value)
Then:

```
var elem = $('#analysis'); //element
var parsed = JSON.parse(elem.attr('data-valuations')); //parse attribute value
var very_satisfied = parsed[0].very_satisfied;
```

Here is [link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Or6ei7XzN1q9zwttaTGl?p=preview) for you

Comment: yes, sorry i have a valid JSON, I just wrote it wrong here, it works now thanks a lot.